# How do we know that spacetime is fabric?

Tags: astrophysics, space-time, general-relativity, space

I have started learning about astronomy as it amazes and inspires me.

I have a question. What led us to believe that spacetime is *fabric*? What is the evidence shows this, and is it considered proven?

If possible Send me the link for research papers so I can learn more.

Please explain in layman's term as I am not a astronomy student but a biology student.

Also let me know books that I can be read.

Comment: Hello.  Your question has already been answered on [physics.se]   Take a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309369/the-fabric-of-space-time The short answer is that "fabric" is a layperson's metaphor, not a scientific term.  If you feel that that doesn't answer your question, please explain further.

Comment: @JamesK An analogy, maybe? Analogies, metaphors, and similes can all be useful in understanding, but only should never take them as literal. Consider this conversation: "I invited your cousin Joe and his wife for dinner tomorrow." "Oh no! He eats like a horse! I don't have enough food for that!" This is not saying that Joe is a subspecies of *Equus ferus*.

Comment: I think the word "fabric" in the expression "the fabric of spacetime" is a metaphor.  The idea that the "fabric of spacetime can be treated like a rubbersheet that bends and, as a result, causes objects to follow paths that appear curved." is an analogy, and a problematic one at best.  See the longer discussions on [physics.se]

Comment: The word 'fabric' is not a layperson's metaphor but frequently used by physicists (see for instance https://www.elsevier.com/books/particle-physics-and-cosmology-the-fabric-of-spacetime/bernardeau/978-0-444-53007-3. ) So I don't know why this question has been closed. To me it is very clear what the OP is asking.